# Table size is reduced to 90% after copying table to another DB

Tags: mysql, indexing, phpmyadmin, primary-key, sqlyog

We are having strange issue of table size. We were trying to reduce table size and to check that we tried to copy one large table size ~27GB to another Test DB on same server using MySQL Yog. And output is strange! Table size is reduced to ~3GB in new DB.

We have compared some random records indexes and everything and it seems everything is same no data is missing. Number of records are exactly same! Both tables seem identical to us.

Can anyone help to understand why table size is reduced ?

Only difference between both DB is Database Collation :

- New DB Collation is **utf8mb4_general_ci**
- Old DB Collation is **latin1_swedish_ci**

No other difference. Both DB on same server, Same fields in Table, It's just copied from one place to another place using SQL Yog.

We also tried to copy some other tables from same DB with size ~3-7 GB, to same test db on same server and also tried to copy same table to another server's DB with same collation and different collation - But we get exact same size over there (Only few MB Difference which is due to Free Data Space)

---

This is Old Table Size (Same is verified in Schema files too)

[image: This is Old Table Size (Same is verified in Schema files too)]

This is New Table Size (Same is verified in Schema files too)
[image: This is New Table Size (Same is verified in Schema files too)]

---

Here is Table Schema :

[image]

Here is Index Details : 
[image]

---

Any help is appreciated for this strange issue !

Comment: That's fragmentation. MySQL does not rearrange the complete table storage every time you delete a row.

Comment: Thanks, But how fragmentation can reduce size from 27 GB to 3 GB ? And why it is not happening to other tables when we copy them to same DB. Also when we do manual defragmentation on same table it does not reduce size to this much. :(

Comment: What version of MySQL (before and after)?

Comment: The image does not show a collation change.  Perhaps the columns are changed, but not the table default?

Comment: @RickJames - Both MySQL Versions are exactly same. it's just new DB on same place.

Comment: Also no columns are changed. Collation in columns is exactly same. Just DB Collation is different.

Comment: Did you delete most of the rows some time in the past?  There is possibly a scenario in which the deletions leave more than the normal amount of fragmentation.  If there was a big deletion, it would be interesting to here the details

Comment: No, There is no big deletions from table in past. Even when we do defragment for existing table it does not reduce size more then 500 MB.

Comment: @RickJames also strange thing was when we try same thing on another server it does not reduce size in actual.